# Where in Hong Kong can I purchase an Octopus card?

Tags: public-transport, hong-kong

Where in Hong Kong can I purchase an Octopus card?

So far I'll I've found on the internet is 7-11 at the airport and some [places](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/cs.html) I cannot find on with google maps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can buy an Octopus at basically at **all transport terminals**.  This includes all MTR stations (including the airport), major light rail stations, major bus and ferry terminals, etc.  Look for the "Customer Service Centre", which is basically the manned ticket booth.

Comment: You can also buy them from most 7-11 or Circle K. It is very unlikely you can walk 100m in any direction without seeing one of these stores (they are more numerous than Starbucks in NY).

Answer (score 14):

### Quick answer:

You can purchase an *"adult Octopus Card"* at Customer Service Centre of **any MTR stations** (**including Airport**, except Racecourse station).

They will give you an [*On-loan Standard Octopus*](https://www.octopus.com.hk/en/consumer/octopus-cards/products/on-loan/standard.html). (See below for more locations)

It will cost you ***HK$150*** (in which HK$100 is the stored value, and HK$50 is refundable deposit).

You can either:

- **return it** and get a refund (including HK$50 deposit and remaining value) in any MTR Customer Service Centre before you leave Hong Kong (HK$9 will be charged if it is returned within 90 days of issue); or
- **keep it** for your next visit (while beware of the possible fee induced).

  > If your On-Loan Adult Octopus is issued on or after 1 October 2017, and has not had any add value or payment transaction for three years, it will become an Inactive Octopus and you may have to pay the *[Inactive Octopus Administrative Fee](https://www.octopus.com.hk/en/consumer/octopus-cards/proper-use/inactive-octopus/index.html)*. If you no longer need it, please return it to us and collect the deposit and remaining value (if any) to avoid the Inactive Octopus Administrative Fee.

Purchasing from convenient stores (7-11 or Circle K) is **not** recommended as it will cost you more. See below for explanation.

---

### More Details:

There are mainly 2 types of Octopus Card (Sold vs On-Loan Octopus).

Majority of local Hongkongers use On-Loan (Standard / Personalised) Octopus. Sold Octopus are mainly designed for tourists.

> A Sold Octopus is a specially designed Octopus sold to you. It holds no deposit. Any remaining value on the Sold Octopus is refundable.
>
> An On-loan Octopus is a card lent by Octopus Cards Limited to you. You are required to pay a refundable deposit that covers the card cost and possible negative value.

If you purchased On-Loan Standard Octopus, you can always apply for a refund (including HK$50 deposit and remaining value) in any MTR Customer Service Centre. **HK$9** will be charged if it is returned within 90 days of issue. [(See refund policy.)](http://www.octopus.com.hk/customer-service/getting-a-refund/en/index.html)

Even so, **for tourist, it is still cheaper to purchase On-Loan Octopus than Tourist Octopus** (unless you want to keep the card after visiting). The selling price (non-refundable) of Tourist Octopus is **HK$39**.

---

### Locations: On-Loan Standard Octopus

On-Loan Standard Octopus can be purchased in following locations. Basically, MTR stations would be the most convenient location to obtain one. [(Official website)](http://www.octopus.com.hk/get-your-octopus/choose-your-octopus/on-loan-octopus/standard-octopus/en/index.html)

> Authorised distribution outlets of Standard Octopus
>
> **MTR Customer Service Centres:**
>   All stations (except Racecourse station)
>
> **Light Rail Customer Service Centres:**
>   Ferry Pier Terminus, Leung King, Town Centre, Yuen Long Terminus and Tin Yat stations
>
> **First Ferry Customer and Octopus Service Centres:**
>   Cheung Chau Pier, Mui Wo Pier, Central Pier 5 & Central Pier 6
>
> **KMB Lok Ma Chau Ticketing Office**

---

### Locations: Sold Tourist Octopus

Sold Tourist Octopus can be purchased in following locations: [(Official website)](http://www.octopus.com.hk/get-your-octopus/choose-your-octopus/limited-edition-octopus/tourist/en/index.html)

> **Available at:**
>
> - 7-Eleven - Click [here](http://www.7-eleven.com.hk/store-locator.aspx) for store-locator
> - CTS (HK) - Click [here](http://www.ctshk.com/english/aboutus/branch_hkgmac.htm) for branch information
> - Circle K - Click [here](http://www.circlek.hk/en/store) for store-locator
> - VanGO - Click [here](http://www.crvanguard.com.hk/upload/images/cvs_plain_en.html) for store-locator
> - Ctrip - Click [here](http://huodong.ctrip.com/activity/2922952.html) for purchase online via Ctrip

Comment: "Majority of local Hongkongers use On-Loan (Standard / Personalised) Octopus. On-Loan Octopus are mainly designed for tourists." Perhaps you mean that _sold_ Octopus Cards are designed for tourists? Otherwise this doesn't make sense. (I also remember that at least some years ago, some Octopus Cards that _did_ hold a deposit could be returned, but that the deposit would be forfeited if the card was returned within a certain amount of time after the initial sale. Is that still the case?)

Comment: thanks @Maroon, typo fixed. some more information about refundable deposit is added.