# How well is AMEX covered in Hong Kong?

Tags: payment-cards, hong-kong

I'm visiting Hong Kong, and I have [AMEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Express). Is it well-covered or should I prepare Visa/MasterCard?

Comment: Same as any other major city. If you are staying in an international hotel, shopping at chain stores, and eating in up-market restaurants, you will have no problem with Amex only. Venture out of the city a little bit and you will find more difficulty. Out in the back streets some places are cash only. I think it's wise to bring a different card with you.

Comment: While you will be able to use AMEX frequently, you will still need cash and then V/MC if you really prefer to use a card.  Note, many places will also let you pay with an Oyster card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amex is well accepted in HK. There are some places that don't take it, but they're not that frequent, and usually mom and pop stores. Having a little cash (or an Octopus card with a few hundred HKD on it) will help, if you only have Amex.

Comment: I knew three people in Hong Kong who I noticed had the black Amex card. I've never seen one anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to prepare Visa / MasterCard as well.

From my general perception, **AMEX** is accepted in bigger merchants only.

**Visa / MasterCard** is well accepted around the city, including almost all restaurants & shops in malls.

Also, it is also good to know that **[Octopus card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65015/where-in-hong-kong-can-i-purchase-an-octopus-card)** is also well accepted for smaller amount transactions, including transportation, convenient stores, supermarkets, etc.

Finally, some smaller merchants accept **cash** only.

(Hongkonger)